# How do I change the login screen colour or background in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, colors, login-screen

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium at home and Professional at work.

How can I change the colour and/or the background image of the lock/login screen? I'd like to set it to something nicer than the default blue with flowers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We actually have a great article on the Super User Blog by [studiohack](https://superuser.com/users/6574/studiohack) about this!

[Bored with your login? Hack it!](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/20/bored-with-your-login-hack-it/)

It's a bit lengthy, but gives you MANY ways of changing it - some are programs, others use the registry.

Comment: Cool! Though I'm surprised you have to go through 3rd part programs / registry hacks. Work computers often deny both methods.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Well if you're on a personal computer thats supplied by work I'm sure its allowed... networked stuff probably wouldnt though.

Comment: @SimonSheehan: Actually, as long as you have admin privileges, it doesn't matter if it is "networked" or not.